# drupal menu and jquery menu

Tags: jquery, drupal, menu

i'm new to drupal , i found that 2 ways to build menu drupal menu module and other one is with [drupal jquery menu](http://drupal.org/project/jquerymenu). i need to know which is best ?and in what basis?. Can any one help me..

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you want to do? It's like asking which is best a hammer or a screwdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking for a comparison between Drupal's Menu module and the jquerymenu module you posted, the question is irrelevant because jquerymenu **uses** Drupal's core Menu module, and just adds a bit of jQuery to it. For the record, [dhtmlmenu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtmlmenu), [nice_menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus), and [simplemenu](http://drupal.org/project/simplemenu) are some other modules that do the same (i.e., modify a regular old Drupal menu with jQuery and perhaps some CSS).

So the answer is that either way you're going to be using Drupal's Menu module. What other modules to use depends on your use case.

- If you want some easy to modify dropdown menus, I'd recommend nice_menus.
- If you want the hierarchical menus to expand and contract when clicked (rather than having to wait for a page load), use dhtmlmenu or jquerymenu.
- If you want a dropdown menu that creates a bar across the top (so that it's sort of separate from the rest of the site), simplemenu works well.